# Adding testID to an element cause malfunction to android talkback

Tags: react-native, accessibility

I have the following React Native code:

```
<View testID={'containerTestID'}>
    <Text>Title</Text>
    <Text>Subtitle</Text>
</View>
```

I'm working on accessibility to my app and found that after adding the `testID` above, I cannot focus on each one of the texts on talkback mode, the talkback focus them together only. This is reproduced in android only.
When removing the `testID`, each of the texts is focused separately as needed for the talkback. But since it is a big app with a lot of tests, removing `testID`s from the components is not an option.

React Native ver. 71.13.
It is not reproduced in iOS.

Can you please advise?
Thanks